# Порядок выполнения обработчиков в event loop

Tags: javascript

Читая [статью из MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) про event-loop, не до конца понял как всё таки обрабатываются события:

1. Событие будет обработано только после того как стек выполнения будет полностью выполнен

или

2. Событие будет обработано в тот момент когда на стеке исполнится контекст в котором было вызвано это событие?

На MDN это объясняется довольно неоднозначно:
`Очередь событий — это список событий, подлежащих обработке. Каждое событие ассоциируется с некоторой функцией. Когда на стеке освобождается достаточно места, событие извлекается из очереди и обрабатывается.`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [визуализация](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=JC5vbignYnV0dG9uJywgJ2NsaWNrJywgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25DbGljaygpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGltZXIoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ1lvdSBjbGlja2VkIHRoZSBidXR0b24hJyk7ICAgIAogICAgfSwgMjAwMCk7Cn0pOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhpISIpOwoKc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0aW1lb3V0KCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkNsaWNrIHRoZSBidXR0b24hIik7Cn0sIDUwMDApOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlbGNvbWUgdG8gbG91cGUuIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D)

Comment: она же https://camo.githubusercontent.com/eb944e1cac2851f2857dfde3d83b8635097820f4/68747470733a2f2f6d656469612e67697068792e636f6d2f6d656469612f336f3735323275536d7a437543794d3469512f736f757263652e676966

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, какая-то битая ссылка: _Non-Image content-type returned_

Comment: @Grundy у меня на chrome/windows и safari/ios открывается =\

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, у меня почему-то нигде не открывается, вот например что EDGE отдает: 
_HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.
GET - https://camo.githubusercontent.com/eb944e1cac2851f2857dfde3d83b8635097820f4/68747470733a2f2f6d656469612e67697068792e636f6d2f6d656469612f336f3735323275536d7a437543794d3469512f736f757263652e676966_

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, в общем не знаю что было :-) но после ошибки в EDGE - начало везде открываться :-D

Comment: перезалил - https://imgur.com/a/3S2DK7F

Comment: Коллеги,  я правильно понял, что очередь обработчиков событий начнет выполнятся только тогда, когда стек вызовов полностью освободится? При этом каждое последующее событие будет исполнятся в свою очередь так же, только после того как стэк вызовов полностью освободится?

Comment: @RomanAndreev, если упрощенно: сначала синхронный код (и синхр.вызовы в том числе) → затем очередь асинхронных коллбэков (в которую попадают коллбэки и таймеров, и слушателей событий, и т.д.).

Comment: Каждый последующий асинхр. коллбэк выполняется после возврата управления предыдущим. Например, в очереди у нас ждут два коллбэка: `A` и `B`, при этом внутри `A` два синхронных вызова, и один аякс-запрос. Сначала интерпретатор полностью выполнит `A` (залезая в каждый синхр. вызов и возвращаясь из него), и только затем приступит к выполнению `B`, и последующих. Обработчик ответа на аякс-запрос из `A` поступит в очередь асинхр. коллбэков - и будет выполнен только после выполнения всех стоящих перед ним.

Comment: Только есть один нюанс: я где-то читал что очередь `requestAnimationFrame()` отдельна от "обычной" очереди асинхронных коллбэков. Не знаю как это реализовано и какой порядок выполнения, но предполагаю что эта очередь выполняется самой последней, непосредственно перед рефлоу и рендерингом документа.